# Regarding abuse of children

Tags: parents

If parents and older siblings who are in charge of their smaller siblings do wrong to a child, e.g

- cursing the child
- injuring the child
- making the child drink alcohol
- neglecting the child

Are there any rules in Islam giving rights to the children?

How will they be accounted for in the day of judgement?

Comment: I'm closing this question because as-written it appears to be a request for personal advice rather than a question about the topic of Islam. Personal issues like this really should be discussed with trusted friends and family or trained professionals, not random strangers on the Internet.